# Showing arrowheads at ends of polyline, not at each segment, using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, line

How do I show arrowheads at the ends of a polyline (not at each segment) using QGIS?

I know I can uncheck **Repeat arrows at each segment,** but that curves the line, which generally isn't what I want to see (and if I have a label on that line, the label stays with the line as digitized, not following the curve). If I then uncheck **Curved arrows,** the line becomes a straight line from end to end of the polyline (but the label stays with the line as digitized).

Answer (score 9):

You can create an arrow on the last x % of the line.

On the line style, use a simple line for the whole line, then add a geometry generator to extract the last 5% (or whatever suits your need), which can then be styled as an arrow.

The expression would be:

```
line_substring( 
   $geometry, 
   length($geometry)*.95,
   length($geometry))
```

The last step would be to use a similar style between the simple line and the arrow so the two merge smoothly

[image]

Another option if you need a simple arrow head is to add a marker line, on the last vertex only, with a rotated triangle marker.

[image]

Comment: A variant to the solution by @JGH : to get the last segment (instead of the last x% of the line) use this expression: `make_line (point_n( geometry(get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id)), -2), point_n( geometry(get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id)), -1))`

Answer (score 4):

Add an arrow-symbol on the end-point of the line:

1. Add a `Symbol layer / Geoemtry Generator / Point` with this expression: `end_point ($geometry)` (screenshot 1)
2. As marker for this symbol-layer point, add a triangle.
3. Use a data driven rotation with this expression (screenshot 2):

   ```
   degrees (azimuth (
     point_n( geometry(get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id)), -2),
     point_n( geometry(get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id)), -1)))
   ```

*Screenshot 1:*

[image]

*Screenshot 2:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you, JHG, for reminding me of what I have done in the past but somehow forgot about. Your second option is the one, with a marker at each end of the line, so three symbol layers: line, arrow left (marker line), and arrow right (marker line). Unfortunately, I don't see anything in the way of modifying arrow length **and** width, or adding my own symbols here, but I'll look some more to see if I missed something.